How to use CenterFace in ML.NET? Model expects shape (10, 3, 32, 32)
I am trying to use CenterFace ONNX in ML.NET and I keep getting various errors, mostly about input size.
CenterFace metadata points that it should have an input of 10, 3, 32, 32, which already makes no sense for image detection - what sense does it make to feed an algorithm with 10 batches, each 32x32 pixels?
Here is my main code:
        string modelPath = "centerface.onnx";
        var mlContext = new MLContext();

        string imagePath = "photo1.jpg";

        var img = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
        var DH = (int)(Math.Ceiling((float)img.Height / 32) * 32);
        var DW = (int)(Math.Ceiling((float)img.Width / 32) * 32);

        var inputData = new[] { new ModelInput { ImagePath = imagePath } };
        IDataView imageData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(inputData);

        var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.LoadImages(outputColumnName: "input.1", imageFolder: "", inputColumnName: nameof(ModelInput.ImagePath))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(outputColumnName: "input.1", imageWidth: DW, imageHeight: DH))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: "input.1"))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(
                outputColumnNames: ["537", "538", "539", "540"],
                inputColumnNames: ["input.1"],
                modelFile: modelPath
            ));

        var model = pipeline.Fit(imageData);
        var predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>(model);
        var prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(new ModelInput { ImagePath = imagePath });

with my 2 model classes:
    public class ModelInput
    {
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    }

    public class ModelOutput
    {
        [ColumnName("537")] 
        public float[] HeatMap { get; set; }

        [ColumnName("538")]
        public float[] Scale { get; set; }

        [ColumnName("539")]
        public float[] Offset { get; set; }

        [ColumnName("540")]
        public float[] Landmarks { get; set; }
    }

But I do keep getting errors about input size:

System.ArgumentException: 'Length of memory (3686400) must match product of dimensions (30720).'

30720 is clearly 10x3x32x32. But again, what sense does it make?
I would think my ONNX is broken but I do have a working implementation using OpenCVSharp:
// Here is computer DW and DH same way as in ML.NET example
CenterFaceParams p = new(image, resizedSize.Width, resizedSize.Height, scoreThreshold, nmsThreshold);
Size size = new(p.DW, p.DH);

using Mat input = new();
Cv2.Resize(image, input, size);

using Mat blobInput = CvDnn.BlobFromImage(input, 1.0, size, new Scalar(0, 0, 0), true, false);
_net.SetInput(blobInput, "input.1");

using (Mat heatMap = new())
using (Mat scale = new())
using (Mat offset = new())
using (Mat landmarks = new())
{
    _net.Forward([heatMap, scale, offset, landmarks], ["537", "538", "539", "540"]);

    CenterFaceDecoder decoder = new(heatMap, scale, offset, landmarks, p);
    return decoder.GetOutput();
}

And this implementation gives me all 4 layers, after modelling I get values I want.

is that model "fully convolutional"? if the thing wants a batch of 10, why do you not give it a batch of 10?

what should be the other 9 images? and still what sense does it make to give it 32x32 image?
I have no idea if this is convolutional honestly, is there a way to check it? https://github.com/Star-Clouds/CenterFace this is their GH
edit: checked centerface.onnx in netron and there are no Gemm layers, if that helps

I suspect it's fully convolutional, with a receptive field of 32x32. one of the output layers appears to be a heatmap. the repo comes with example code. perhaps you can take inspiration from that. ML.NET would have to be capable of interpreting the ONNX correctly. maybe it fails at that. IDK.

I tried various things like preprocessing image to float[] etc. but every approach results with a fact that my output is not a size of 10x3x32x32.
